# Similar git tags to trigger Github Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-tag

Currently I have 2 Github Action. One for production release, and the other one for staging release.

When I push a tag in production branch it triggers the CI/CD:

```yaml
name: Deploy production

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
```

And when I "simply" push a commit to the develop branch it trigger the other CI/CD:

```yaml
name: Deploy staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
```

What I would like to achieve now, is to trigger production and staging actions with different, but similar git tag. I only know how to write down the "filter" in regex, but not how should I implement it in Github Actions.

For production:

```
/^v\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}/i
```

This captures strings from `v0.0.0` up to `v99.99.99`

For staging:

```
/^v\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}-rc\.\d{1,2}/i
```

This captures strings from `v0.0.0-rc.0` up to `v99.99.99-rc.99`

My best guesses are these:

Production

```yaml
name: Deploy production

on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - main
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

Staging

```yaml
name: Deploy production

on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - develop
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-rc.[0-9]+'
```

May I ask for help, how to implement my idea properly?

---

Sources:

1. [Workflow Syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore)
2. [Filter pattern cheat sheat](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to answer here, you've got tag filters that appear to be what you're after. The only thing to point out here is that the `branches:` condition is a separate check. The tag filter and the branches are an *OR*, not an *AND*. So it's either up to you to make sure you only ever tag commits in those branches, or to include a step in an initialising job that checks that the triggering tag is on the expected branch.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure in my answer and there is no external tool to test it. Also thanks for pointing out the condition.